# why amplitude changes when i use addition of my heaviside

Tags: matlab, simulink

i've defined each function alone and plot it then made the addition of the functions then plot them all together using subplot .

```
%with using heaviside
clc;clear
t=-5:1/1000:+5
u1=heaviside(t-2)
u2=heaviside(t+1)
u3=heaviside(t+4)
X=u1+u2+u3
subplot(411)
plot(t,u1,'r');grid on
subplot(412)
plot(t,u2,'r');grid on
subplot(413)
plot(t,u3,'r');grid on
subplot(414)
plot(t,X,'r');grid on
```

[image: this is the picture of the result]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code to the question.

Comment: thanks for the answer 
i thought the code is needless at first ,but i've add the code

Comment: Any detail like this will help to track the problem. I fixed the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `X` is the sum of 3 `heaviside` functions with different time-shifts, meaning it has a total value of `3*1` (for `t` to infinity).

If you want the 3 step function `X` to have an amplitude of 1, you have to divide by 3.

```
clc;clear
t=-5:1/1000:+5;
u1=heaviside(t-2);
u2=heaviside(t+1);
u3=heaviside(t+4);
X=(u1+u2+u3)/3;
```

Comment: @MouadSama If this solved your problem, consider voting on it or marking it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)